# Create function to retrieve ID from table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a function that retrieves a student's id, as far as I know sqlite doesn't support the creation of functions natively so I used [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) as a reference, however I can't quite understand how the code works.

Suppose I have the following table: *students*

```
id | name
--------------------
1  | Jane Appleseed
2  | John Doe
```

I tried the following and, of course, it fails:

```
def getCourseID(s):
    return cur.execute('SELECT id FROM students WHERE name = ? ', (s, ))
```

What would be the correct way to implement a function such as this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
def getCourseID(s):
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM students WHERE name = ? ', (s, ))
    results = list(cur)
    if results:
        return results[0][0]
    return None # nothing was found...
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Though I had to create a new connection to the database inside the function, am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: You don't need a new connection for each query, you can reuse connections and also cursors. just pass a cursor/connection to the function